# Make advanced number calculations? 2.1k equal to 2100 etc..?

Tags: java, numbers

So as the title says, if the input for example was `2.1k` it should equal to `2100`, if it was `3.7k` it would be `3700` and so on. I have some code as following, I haven't really tried anything, just thinking about how the formula could be:

```
String arg = args[0];
if(arg.contains("k")) {
    args[0].replace("k", "000");
}
```

Comment: Well, that snippet you posted adds one too many zeroes, and it also doesn't remove the decimal point.

Comment: "...I havent really tried anything..." -- You should do that, then if you get stuck, come back and ask a question about the specific difficulty you're having.

Comment: `.replace` doesn't change the string, it returns the modified string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the `arg` ends with "k", if it does parse the double value preceeding every character before "K" and multiply by 1000. Something like

```
String arg = "2.1k";
if (arg.endsWith("k")) {
    int val = (int) (Double.parseDouble(arg.substring(0, arg.length() - 1))
           * 1000);
    arg = String.valueOf(val);
}
System.out.println(arg);
```

Outputs

```
2100
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `k` example it would be:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(arg, "k");//count the amount of k's
double decNumber = Double.parseDouble(arg.replace("k", "");//removes all k's and parse to a double
double finalNumber = decNumber * Math.pow(1000, k);//multiple by 1000^k
```

This works for any amount of k's *AFTER* the decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this looks more like:

```
String arg = args[0];
        if(arg.contains("k")) {

           newVal = args[0].replace("k", "");  //just drop the K and be left with a decimal
            newVal = parseInt(args[0] * 1000);  //New value is whatever was passed in times 1000
        }
```

Comment: I think my answer me be more JavaScripty than Java.  But you get the idea.

Comment: Strings are immutable. `replace` creates new string, not affects old one.